# Edit XML node in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to edit a node in .xml file but i can't get it working.

My XML:

```
<configuration>
  <car title="Ferrari">
    <url>http://www.ferrari.com</url>
  </car>
</configuration>
```

My code in c#:

```
    string var_x = "Ferrari";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("Config.xml");
    XmlNode itemTitle = doc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/car[@title = '" + var_x + "']");
    XmlNode itemUrl = doc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/car[@title = '" + var_x + "']/url");


    itemTitle.InnerText = texbox_title.Text;
    itemUrl.InnerText = textbox_url.Text;

    doc.Save("Config.xml");
```

I can't get code above working for my xml. I can't edit that node. Maybe a problem with XPath but i can't figure out why it's not working properly.

My XML after using c# code above:

```
<configuration>
  <car title="Ferrari">NEW_NAME</car>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is this your application configuration file?

Comment: What is your desired outcome and the concrete problem?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Yeah, i'm using xml as my app configuration file.

Comment: @Markus the above code doesn't work because it doesn't edit that node.

Comment: FYI the language is named "C#", not "Csharp"

Comment: @ufo: Any exceptions? How do you want the XML to look like afterwards and how does it look like? Does it just not Change at all?

Comment: @JohnSaunders C# equals "CSharp" according to wikipedia :)

Comment: Please point to the wikipedia article so that I can correct it. The language may be _pronounced_ "C Sharp", but it is not spelled that way.

Comment: @Markus none exceptions. The code above doesn't change "title" from car and cleans `<url></url>`. I just updated first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to change the value of the attribute title of the car element, change your code as follows:

```
 XmlElement itemTitle = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/car[@title = '" + var_x + "']");
 XmlNode itemUrl = doc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/car[@title = '" + var_x + "']/url");

 itemTitle.Attributes["title"].Value = texbox_title.Text;
 itemUrl.InnerText = textbox_url.Text;
```

In your version, the complete inner text of the car element (including the url sub-element) is overwritten by the car title.
In addition, you need to cast the result of SelectSingleNode to XmlElement as this has the Attributes collection.

Comment: I can't get "Attributes" recognized. Can you tell me what imports needed?

Comment: @ufo: You need to cast the result of SelectSingleNode. I've updated my sample.

Answer (score 0):

The property `InnerText` refers to everything which is text, so you are replacing the content of the car element, including the url element with the line:

```
itemTitle.InnerText = texbox_title.Text;
```

Use the following instead:

```
itemTitle.Attributes["title"].Value = texbox_title.Text;
itemUrl.InnerText = textbox_url.Text;
```